# How to insert a new array key value and store in a session using PHP?

Tags: php, session

I need a little help here. In my page I have a summary product list and in that  page I need to store all my parent id in a session. But only the last id I can store. How can I store all the products ID as the key and the quantity as a values in a session?

Here's my sample code:

```
fprintr($get_product);

        foreach($get_product as $product_detail) {

            if ($product_detail['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_detail['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height'));
            } else {
                $image = false;
            }

            $search_data[] = array(
                'product_id' => $product_detail['product_id'],
                'code' => $product_detail['code'],
                /*'name'        => str_replace('||','<br/>',$result['name']),*/
                'product_name' => str_replace('||',' ', $product_detail['product_name']),
                'description' => html_entity_decode($product_detail['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
                'image' => $image,
                'price' => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_detail['price'], 0, 0)),
                'quantity' => $product_detail['quantity'],
                'update' => $this->url->link('giftregistry/registrymanage/viewRegistryDetail'),
                'remove' => $this->url->link('giftregistry/registrymanage/viewregistrydetail', '&remove=' . $product_detail['product_id'] . '&code=' . $product_detail['code']),
            );

            $this->session->data['cart']= array(
                $product_detail['product_id'].'::' => $product_detail['quantity']
            );

        }

        fprintr($this->session->data);
```

Here's my array sample:

This is the initial load of my products from the database

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 56
            [product_name] => Luminarc Rhodes Ice Bucket
            [price] => 300.00
            [quantity] => 1
            [code] => S6-214347
            [description] => <p>Luminarc Rhodes Ice Bucket</p>

            [image] => data/metro/products/Wine and Dine/08.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 57
            [product_name] => Regent Cheese Board with Knife
            [price] => 2949.00
            [quantity] => 1
            [code] => S6-214347
            [description] => <p>Regent Cheese Board with Knife</p>

            [image] => data/metro/products/Wine and Dine/02.jpg
        )

)
```

Here's my session cart after updating

```
[cart] => Array
        (
            [57::] => 1
        )
```

As you can see the last product id is stored. How can I save all the product IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$this->session->data['cart'][] = array(
        $product_detail['product_id'].'::' => $product_detail['quantity']
);
```

This will be resolve your problem.